# Java Jar import failing

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, import

In Eclipse/Selenium, all of Java "import" statements on all of my tests fail. Any advice on what I am missing?[Import indicating Red (x) on all of my tests in Selenium[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQoV2.jpg)]

Comment: Looks like some referenced libraries (JARs) are missing in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_.

Comment: thx, I have checked, but will check again.